# Java StringBuilder to CSV

Tags: java, csv, stringbuilder

I have a scenario where I need to fetch some values from multiple web services and write all those values as a comma separated values (CSV). To achieve this, I am appending all values to StringBuilder with Comma(,) as a Separator and Printing the string as below and saving it as a csv:

```
3,,069529781,,069529781,,viewerRole
```

But I want to add some headers to all of these values. For ex: id, name, email, role and then values like below:

```
action,userId,firstName,lastName
```

So I am adding those manually in csv file. If I want to add these headers also dynamically and write all the values to CSV file, How to do that ? Please help me resolving this. Here is my code:

```
if (usersList.totalCount != 0 && usersList.totalCount >= 1) {
                System.out.println("usersList.totalCount ----->"
                        + usersList.totalCount);
                for (User user : usersList.objects) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        if (user.id != null) {
                            String userRole = getUserRole(user.id);
                            String cnum = getUserUniqueId(user.email);
                            if (user.id != null) {
                                sb.append(user.id);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                            }
                            String action = "1";

                            if (cnum != null) {
                                if (userRole == null) {
                                    action = "3";
                                }
                            } else {
                                action = "3";
                            }
                            if (cnum != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(cnum);
                            }

                            if (action != null) {
                                sb1.append(action);
                            }
                            if (cnum != null) {
                                sb1.append(",").append(cnum);
                            } else {
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }

                            if (user.firstName != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(user.firstName);
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.firstName);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }
                            if (user.lastName != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(user.lastName);
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.lastName);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }
                            if (user.screenName != null) {
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.screenName);
                            } else {
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }

                            if (userRole != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(userRole);
                                // sb1.append(",").append(userRole);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                // action = "3";
                                // sb1.append(action);
                            }
                            // sb1.append("1");
                            if (user.email != null) {
                                sb.append(",").append(user.email);
                                sb1.append(",").append(user.email);
                            } else {
                                sb.append(",");
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }

                            if (userRole != null) {
                                sb1.append(",").append(userRole);
                            } else {
                                sb1.append(",");
                            }

                            if (user.partnerData != null) {
                                if (user.partnerData.startsWith("pw")
                                        && user.partnerData.length() == 43) {
                                    sb.append(",");
                                }
                                if (user.partnerData.length() > 43) {
                                    String partnerData = user.partnerData
                                            .substring(44);
                                    sb.append(",").append(partnerData);
                                }
                                if (!user.partnerData.startsWith("pw")) {
                                    sb.append(",").append(user.partnerData);
                                }
                            }
                            sb.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                            sb1.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            System.out.println(sb);
            System.out.println(sb1);
        }
```

Comment: You can make life a lot easier for yourself by separating out the logic of building the row contents from the writing of the row to CSV. And also by writing a method which returns `""` if the string is null, and the string itself otherwise, e.g. `(string != null) ? string : ""`.

Comment: You dont need to write your own CSV writer. Look at  https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-csv/

Comment: @Andy - Can you please give me a sample code. I am getting error with the given code.